# Replying to "Shall we…" with "…if we shall"

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, conditional-constructions

My friend asked me:

> Shall we head up to the North again?

I'm wondering about the suggestion. Is it correct to answer with:

> I am wondering if we shall?

or:

> I am wondering if we should?

Also, I am having problems with my punctuation with the above. Are they correct?

Comment: It's **should** not **shall** - and the question mark after **I am wondering if we should** (which is not a question) should be moved to **Shall we head up to the north again (which is). Small **n** for north, unless it's the name of something - and more idiomatic would be **head north** or **head up north**.

Comment: I see, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **should**, not shall.

If you're wondering if you should, that's not a question, it's a statement. So use a period. Also, North should probably not be capitalized.

> Shall we head up north?
>
> I'm wondering if we should.